# Looping Parameter in Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have a  FOR loop in my action transaction.  I need to run the loop for certain times before exiting the transaction. I am passing a parameter which need to be used throughout loop and move to the next value in I+1 condition. I have set the parameter setting to EACH OCCURRENCE. How can I force to use the same parameter( which is called multiple time) in each loop?

Answer (score 1):

copy your dynamic parameter string which is changing to another string variable before you enter the loop.  Then use your static string for replacements inside of the loop.